# Create a revolved 3D image of a line

Tags: plotting, image3d

```
p = {{0, 0}, {3, 2}, {6, 10}, {9, 8}, {12, 7}, {15, 9}, {18, 9}};
Graphics[Line[p]]
```

These are the x,y coordinates I got to work with in order to make a line and then make the whole thing rotate to form a 3D image.

I've tried to use RevolutionPlot3D but I only get a cone. None of the points gets used.

How do i do to get an image like this and calculate the volume of the body?
[image: Example image]

//Update
I was forbidden to use Interpolation ("Too advanced command for this"-Teacher)
So I have to solve it without that command and am forced to make functions for every point in the line... yay...

Comment: does `intF = Interpolation[p, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
RevolutionPlot3D[intF[t], {t, p[[1, 1]], p[[-1, 1]]}, 
 RevolutionAxis -> "X"]` give what you need?

Comment: Yes! It does! =)

Now I can get onto trying to figure out how to calculate the volyme of the thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For a fixed point  `{x, r} ∈ Line[p]`, we can get a disk  `y^2 + z^2 <= r^2`,this is the intuitive that  we use to  construct the rotation solid.

```
p = {{0, 0}, {3, 2}, {6, 10}, {9, 8}, {12, 7}, {15, 9}, {18, 9}};
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, y, z}, {x, r} ∈ Line[p] && 
     y^2 + z^2 <= r^2}, {r, x, y, z}];
Volume[reg]
Region[reg]
```

> `977 π`

[image]

```
p = {{0, 0}, {3, 2}, {6, 10}, {9, 8}, {12, 7}, {15, 9}, {18, 9}};
parametrics = (1 - t)*#1 + t*#2 & @@@ Partition[p, 2, 1];
RevolutionPlot3D[parametrics // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}, 
 RevolutionAxis -> "X", Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
p = {{0, 0}, {3, 2}, {6, 10}, {9, 8}, {12, 7}, {15, 9}, {18, 9}};
parametrics = (1 - t)*#1 + t*#2 & @@@ Partition[p, 2, 1];
regs = ParametricRegion[{#1, #2*r*Cos[θ], #2*r*
       Sin[θ]}, {{r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 
       2 π}}] & @@@ parametrics;
regs // Volume
% // Total
```

> `{4 π, 124 π, 244 π, 169 π, 193 π, 243 π}`

> `977 π`

Comment: Mathematica went into an endless loop for some reason when I tried to run the code

Comment: That is a brilliant answer

@JohanGrankvist Just a quick comment; I managed to fully execute the answer given here. My version is "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)". Can I suggest that you quit the kernel and try again?

Comment: Sorry but I run the reg=ParametricRegion... fine but when it comes to Volume[reg] it freezes.

Answer (score 3):

```
p = {{0, 0}, {3, 2}, {6, 10}, {9, 8}, {12, 7}, {15, 9}, {18, 9}};

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[p[[All, 1]]];
```

As kglr suggested

```
intF = Interpolation[p, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Show[
 RevolutionPlot3D[intF[x],
  {x, xmin, xmax},
  RevolutionAxis -> "X",
  ViewPoint -> Front,
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{#[[1]], 0, #[[2]]} & /@ p]}]]
```

[image]

```
sectionVol = 
 Entity["Surface", "ConicalFrustum"][EntityProperty["Surface", "Volume"]]
```

[image]

```
vol = Total[
  sectionVol @@@ ({#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]], #[[2, 1]] - #[[1, 1]]} & /@ 
     Partition[p, 2, 1])]

(* 977 π *)

vol // N

(* 3069.34 *)
```